# Can MutableLiveData have a subclass as it's type?

Tags: android, kotlin, inheritance, mutablelivedata

I am having trouble with passing `MutableLiveData<Subclass>` as an argument when the parameter is `MutableLiveData<Superclass>`. The trouble being that my app won't build and I get a: **DataBinderMapperImpl error: cannot find symbol.**

This works:

`fun display(list: List<SuperClass>)`

While calling `instance.display(subClassList)`

This doesn't:

`fun display(liveData: MutableLiveData<Superclass>)`

While calling `instance.display(subClassLiveData)`.

Just to clarify, I can pass the subclass as the argument if it's anything other than LiveData. But if it's LiveData, my app won't build.

Answer (score 1):

When your function takes a parameter that has a generic type that is not narrowed with `in` or `out`, you can't pass anything besides that exact type.

List and LiveData are already defined with an `out` type (covariant), so a `List<Subtype>` qualifies as a `List<Supertype>` and a `LiveData<Subtype>` qualifies as a `LiveData<Supertype>`.

But the mutable variants of these classes (MutableList and MutableLiveData) have methods for changing what is in them, so their type has to be able to go both in and out. You can't allow a supertype or a subtype because it will break functionality in one direction.

If you define your function like this:

```
fun display(list: MutableLiveData<out SuperClass>)
```

then you'll be able to pass a `MutableLiveData<Subclass>` to it fine. You just won't be able to call `setValue` on it from inside the `display` function.